# can't stop stretching of the elements using flexbox

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, advanced-custom-fields

I want in WordPress website using Advancing Custom Fields to show tweets in 3 columns as in the image below
[image]

but the problem is that every 3 tweets is stretching as long as the highest tweet of them which give bad appearance

and that's the code I use to show these tweets

```
    <?php 
if ( is_admin() ) :
    simple_block( 'Twitter Showcase', null, '#824790' );
else : ?>
    <div class="block" data-block-type="twitter-showcase">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-start">
                <?php
                    $count = count(get_field('tweets'));
                    while ( $count) : the_row();
                    $tweet = get_sub_field( 'tweet' );
                ?>
                <div class="col-4 mb-32">
                        <?php echo $count; ?>
                        <?php echo $tweet; ?>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif;
```

I had an idea to solve this problem or how to get a row by id so I can make three columns and loop throw tweets Sequentially between these three columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it with the CSS property column-count

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what the problem is. Can you describe it more clearly? Offhand, it sounds like you need to use flexbox or grid.